# Is it possible to make android library contains readme.txt?

Tags: android, gradle

I am new in Gradle.

I've been made android library and I will upload this into maven repository.

But is it possible to add "Readme.txt" into my library?

for example,

When someone add my library into dependencies section in build.gradle and sync.
then Gradle creates(or copy) "Readme.txt" into target project(probably $projectDir or $projectDir/app) and user can read it(Like NuGet)

(Important things of this library, how to use example or something like that.)

I think it is really annoying visit project web-site and read "How to use" every  using single library.

I want my library contains how to use text file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think this is possible, you don't know how the calling use is referencing your project. They are likely only referencing the compiled source code and never running your gradle file.
2. This is not a good idea, you don't know their exact folder structure, and even if you did you can not be sure that your readme.txt would have a unique name that did not conflict with their project file.s

Comment: ty for answer. but I want to manage dependency like NuGet. NuGet's nupkg file can contains readme file or another files for build. anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using a .jar file you cannot include this as resources cannot be compiled into it. But you can export your library as an *.aar file which can contain resource files. You get this by using "*com.android.library*" as your plugin type and can then find the aar-file in your build folder after you have built it.
This can then be included in your other project e.g. as a file reference.

Comment: plugin type? is it differ from library type module? can you explain more information or reference manuals? thak you for your hint!

Comment: See this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects

Comment: no problem. mark this as the correct answer if your issue was solved ;)